# launch another android app on a new thread

Tags: java, android, multithreading

I am trying to calculate the time taken by the app(**Child app**) to load, hit a query and populate the screen. For this purpose i have created another simple app(**Parent app**) with just on button. On click of this button the Child app is launched for some number of iterations. I am able to invoke the child app from parent app, but the parent app doesn't wait for child app to finish execution.

Here is the **onClick** code snippet in the Parent app:

```
public void onClick(View v) {
    Intent launchIntent = this.getPackageManager().getLaunchIntentForPackage("com.example.android.packagename");
    //null pointer check in case package name was not found.
    if (launchIntent != null) {
        try {
            long launchStartTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
            launchIntent.putExtra("LaunchStartTime", launchStartTime);
            System.out.println("Launching child app");
            /*Call child app 10 times. */
            for (int i = 0; i <= 10; i++) {
                startActivity(launchIntent); 
                /*Parent app doesn't waits for child app to finish its execution, and below statement is executed.*/
                System.out.println("This will be printed and child app is launched only once.");
            }
        } catch (ActivityNotFoundException err) {
            Toast t = Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"App not found", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
            t.show();
        }
    }
}
```

The solution could be to use multi-threading, but i have no experience in that area. Could any one provide a way to make parent app wait for child app to finish its execution and possibly iterate for desired number of times.

**EDIT:**

Now I am trying to invoke the app just once on child thread. I tried to spawn a child thread from main thread and invoke the child app on child thread,

but I am getting below error:

> java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.app.ActivityThread$ApplicationThread android.app.ActivityThread.getApplicationThread()' on a null object reference

This is the new **onClick** code snippet:

```
public void onClick(View v) {
    MyRunnable runnable = new MyRunnable();
    Thread thread = new Thread(runnable);
    thread.start();
}
```

And here is the **MyRunnable** class that implements **runnable** interface.

```
public class MyRunnable extends AppCompatActivity implements Runnable  {
@Override
public void run() {
    Intent launchIntent = ApplicationContextProvider.getContext().getPackageManager().getLaunchIntentForPackage("com.example.android.packagename");
    if (launchIntent != null) {
        try {
             startActivity(launchIntent);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
}
```

Comment: you could try AsyncTask, in doInBackground() you can perform the task and in postExecute you can call another app.

Comment: @kiranMalvi's solution would work. You can reference https://stackoverflow.com/a/9671602/1275764 to see how the AsyncTask is implemented. (:

Comment: What about "startActivityForResults()"? https://developer.android.com/training/basics/intents/result